# Best way to localize an entity?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I have an entity named  Status where I store different status. I have two properties for this entity: IdStatus and Name.

This entity is filled like this:

```
IdStatus: 1 - Name: Open
IdStatus: 2 - Name: Closed
IdStatus: 3 - Name: Deleted
```

I retrieve my status like this:

```
    [HttpGet]
    private void RetrieveMyStatus(MyViewModel model)
    {
        var sta = entities.Status.Select(o => new SelectListItem { Text = o.Name, Value = o.IdStatus.ToString() }).ToList();
        model.Status = sta;
    }
```

As you can see, until now, I manage only english. But now, I would like to manage french also.

I think I had to adapt my entity like this:

```
IdStatus: 1 - NameEN: Open - NameFR: Ouvert
IdStatus: 2 - NameEN: Closed - NameFR: Fermé
IdStatus: 3 - NameEN: Deleted - NameFR: Supprimé
```

How can I adapt my function RetrieveMyStatus in order to get the french or english Name property depending of the culture of the user? (stored in sessionWrapper.Culture) I don't figure out what is the best way?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the `Name` values in a strongly typed `Resource`. Then define a resx file for the other localized resources you may need to serve up. For example, you would have a default and this would be in Resources.resx. If you also need to serve French resources too then create a Resources.fr.resx file with the French strings in (the keys need to be the same in both)

This will then use the Current UICulture of the Request to get the `Name` out of the appropriate resource file.

Comment: I prefer using an entity to store my Status because I have defined constraints with other entities. I'm searching for a different solution that you propose. Maybe we can adapt my actual solution for localizing? Thanks anyway.

Comment: Finally I used this solution. The drawback is that I only have a key (1, 2, 3) in my Status entity and need to look into a resource file to obtain the descriptions... Thanks.